# Fix background image on Scrollview Android

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

When I use Scrollview in my codes my background image stretches and scrolls with buttons. I want just buttons scroll, not the background. I have attached a related image that you can figure this out.
Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="@drawable/back"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/app"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"

                />

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/moshiri"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the background image on the ScrollView and add Padding to the ScrollView or Margins to the Linearlayout.

Comment: this works but be careful as scrollview performance is sensitive to image size

Answer (score 9):

This thing worked fine for me.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gearImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/imageName" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

make 1 Linearlayout at root instead of scrollview and `use android:background="@drawable/back"` to that layout as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/app"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moshiri"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here I am assuming that your `@drawable/back` is your given image background

Comment: I want buttons scroll.

Comment: Background stretches and scrolls yet. Nothing changed.

Comment: No difference. Still stretching

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The image was resized automatically and filled the entire background (Adjusted on width and cropped on height.)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/app_back_image" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Raanan said, set the background image on the ScrollView, but to prevent backround from streching on different screen size, you can add gravity to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/back"
android:gravity="top" />
```

Comment: What is that code for? I don't see anything in my layout and app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/app"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"

                />

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/moshiri"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".CadetEnrollmentFormActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<!--put your view here -->


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: could be better if you add some explanation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout as a root element of ScrollView.
Then set your background to Linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    .......
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    
    <ScrollView
        ........>
        
        <LinearLayout
            .......>
            //your code hear
        <LinearLayout/>
    <ScrollView/>       
<LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your manifest to the respective activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```